# How in SQLite can i delete a repeated database table rows that have the same name if these repeated rows are associated with rows in another table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a two tables. 1. restaurants, 2.menuItems. the menuItems rows are associated with the restaurants using their primary key as foreign keys. Now I have some restaurants with the same name and I want to remove them except one, also, I want to remove the associated items in  menuItems table. how can I do that using sqlite query? I tried this without any success, i got syntax error.

```
Delete  FROM restaurant inner join menu_item  on restaurant.id=menu_item.restaurant_id
WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT min(name)
                    from restaurant
                    group by id)
```

Comment: If you have the foreign keys in the menuitems table set up as `ON DELETE CASCADE` that part is taken care of automatically by deleting the records from the restaurant table, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not support DELETE statements with joins.
This query:

```
select min(id)
from restaurant
group by name;
```

returns all the restaurant ids that you will **not** delete (keeps the minimum `id` for each name).
So use it to delete all the the rows from `menu_item` that have other `restaurant_id`s:

```
delete from menu_item
where restaurant_id not in (select min(id) from restaurant group by name);
```

and to delete  all the the rows from `restaurant` that have other `id`s:

```
delete from restaurant
where id not in (select min(id) from restaurant group by name);
```

If you defined the foreign key `restaurant_id` in `menu_item` with the option `ON DELETE CASCADE`, then the step for deleting the rows from `menu_item` would be done automatically.
Read more here: [SQLite Foreign Key](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-foreign-key/)